# Multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven for same java project

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I want to use different selenium versions (3.141.59 and 4.1.0) for running my project in chrome and firefox browser and android,
Is it possible to use different version of selenium dependency in POM for different browsers in same JAVA project?, if so how it will code.

Comment: Update the question with the conditions to decide when to use which version?

Answer (score 0):

You can define, but only one will be picked at a time !

**As per maven documentation**

*Dependency mediation - this determines what version of an artifact will be chosen when multiple versions are encountered as dependencies. Maven picks the "nearest definition". That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins*

**Read more about it here**
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Ideally I'll suggest to you to use a stable version of selenium compatible with both browsers !